# How to make Online iPhone "Card Game" with HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, css, game-engine

What are the necessary things for creating card game on iPhone??

The purpose of this app is to share the ideas by using cards.
Each player will draw a card and do what the cards order to do such as write the comments on those topics and so on.

I'm quite new for the programing. I don't want to learn Objective-C. It is quite hard for me. 
I have searched on google that PhoneGab can port HTML5,CSS&JavaScript to be an iPhone app.
So the things that I must learn are HTML5,CSS & JavaScript only?

This app must have many players to play for sharing the ideas. Therefore, must I learn other programing languages? such as, php.. to manage each player data (profile).

Moreover, I would like to use points, badges, leader board in this app, too

How about and SDK or any software to help me write code easier?

(p.s. Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great idea!

You will probably have to learn all that languages and depending on the things you want php will be included...

My advice: if you are new on programming and will have to study a while, I say it is better to do a native iPhone app. A web app will have tons of things you will have to worry about so the app can run on different devices... So, will be more complicated to deal with that kind of stuff than learn and develop a native iPhone app...

Including that you want to use features like badges and leaderboards, all native on each device, so you don't have to worry on creating something from zero, like in a web app...

I hope it helped!

Comment: @CarinaPilar: Thank you so much for your advice!
Do you have any suggestion for e-book that I should start from?

Comment: @ArdtaNgonphachanh, I liked this [book](http://www.amazon.com/iPhone-iOS-6-Development-Essentials/dp/1479211419/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1380458673&sr=8-1&keywords=iphone+ios+6+development+essentials). But there is a lot of sources, Stackoverflow helped me a lot too!